# Avoid Update of resources in Terraform

Tags: digital-ocean, terraform, blue-green-deployment

Currently we are using the Blue/Green Deployment Model for our Application using Terraform.

And our TF Files have resources for both Blue & Green as seen below -

```
resource "aws_instance" "green_node" {
  count = "${var.node_count * var.keep_green * var.build}"

  lifecycle = {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }

  ami                         = "${var.green_ami_id}"
  instance_type               = "${lookup(var.instance_type,lower(var.env))}"
  security_groups             = "${split(",", lookup(var.security_groups, format("%s-%s", lower(var.env),var.region)))}"
  subnet_id                   = "${element(split(",", lookup(var.subnets, format("%s-%s", lower(var.env),var.region))), count.index)}"
  iam_instance_profile        = "${var.iam_role}"
  key_name                    = "${var.key_name}"
  associate_public_ip_address = "false"

  tags {
    Name            = "node-green-${var.env}-${count.index + 1}"
  }

  user_data = "${data.template_cloudinit_config.green_node.rendered}"

}


resource "aws_instance" "blue_node" {
  count = "${var.node_count * var.keep_blue * var.build}"

  lifecycle = {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }

  ami                         = "${var.blue_ami_id}"
  instance_type               = "${lookup(var.instance_type,lower(var.env))}"
  security_groups             = "${split(",", lookup(var.security_groups, format("%s-%s", lower(var.env),var.region)))}"
  subnet_id                   = "${element(split(",", lookup(var.subnets, format("%s-%s", lower(var.env),var.region))), count.index)}"
  iam_instance_profile        = "${var.iam_role}"
  key_name                    = "${var.key_name}"
  associate_public_ip_address = "false"

  tags {
    Name              = "node-blue-${var.env}-${count.index + 1}"
  }
  user_data = "${data.template_cloudinit_config.blue_node.rendered}"

}
```

My question - Is there a way to update the Green Resources without updating the Blue Resources and vice versa **`Without Using Targeted Plan`**. For eg. If we update the Security Groups`(var.security_groups)` which is a common variable, the update will occur for both Blue and Green and i will have to do a targeted plan`(seen below)`to avoid Blue Resources from getting updated with the New Security Group's -

```
terraform plan -out=green.plan -target=<green_resource_name>
```

Comment: How do you want to call terraform? I don't think you can swap between green and blue automatically every time you run it, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: I am currently doing a Targeted Plan to stop the update of Blue Resources if i want to Update Green. I wanted to know if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good question.

If you need to make the blue/green stack work as your expect and reduce the complexity of the code, You can [use terraform modules](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/usage.html), and set a variable to control which color you will update.

So the stack shares the module when you need update blue or green resources. Define a variable, such as `TF_VAR_stack_color` to blue or green

Add `${var.stack_color}` in the name of any resources you try to create/update in modules.

```
module "nodes" {
  source  = "modules/nodes"
  name    = "${var.name}-${var.stack_color}-${var.others}"
  ...
}
```

So you can deploy the blue resource with below command without impact the running green resources.

```
TF_VAR_stack_color=blue terraform plan
```

or

```
terraform plan -var stack_color=blue
```

With terraform modules, you needn't write resource `aws_instance` two times for blue and green nodes.

I will recommend splitting the resources into different state files by `terraform init`, so they will be the totally separate stacks.